# Use device tree or Kconfig to load a driver

Tags: configuration, embedded, yocto, device-tree, grub2-mkconfig

I would like to add and enable a new device in an embedded Linux image.

Is it enough to just specify the information in a device tree file and then the driver for the device will get loaded based on the information?

Or must I also use Kconfig to enable this?

Comment: "enable a new device" ? Do you mean a new driver ? Some driver not already in-kernel built ? not already modeprobed at init time ? Is this driver available in your linux kernel distribution ? What is your init system ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes I mean enable a new driver which is not built into the kernel yet. Not already modeprobed at init time. This would be a new driver that I must add to the kernel. I am using systemd